# Firebase currentUser.emailVerified return false after clicking the verification link and signing out

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication

After getting an email and clicking the verification link, the Firebase system doesn't update the emailVerified status. Whenever I console.log it, I always get false.

I tried adding the following to see if the problem can be solved, but without any success

```
user?.reload().then(()=>{ 

    console.log("emailVerified: "+user?.emailVerified); 

})
```

Also, I tried signing out and in manually, but to no avail.

Below in the console.log is what I get: false.

[image]

The following is the full detail of my code.

I create a method to **keep track of the emailVerified status** and invoke it whenever I sign in (not a standard Firebase SDK, but a customized function for me to check the emailVerifiedStatus easily):

```
export const firebaseAuthServiceEmailVerifiedStatus=()=>{
    const auth = getAuth();
    auth.currentUser?.reload().then(()=>{
        if(auth.currentUser?.emailVerified as boolean){
            console.log("email has been verified");
        }else{
            console.log("email has not been verified");
        }
    })
}
```

Below is the code for **sending a verification email** when users successfully sign up with their email and password:

```
export const firebaseAuthServiceEmailVerification=(setEmailVerificationSent:(isSuccess:boolean|undefined)=>void)=>{
    const auth = getAuth();
    if (auth.currentUser) {
        console.log("auth.currentUser.email: "+auth.currentUser.email);
        sendEmailVerification(auth.currentUser)
            .then(() => {
                setEmailVerificationSent(true);
                console.log("Email Verification has been sent!");
                // Email verification sent!
                // ...
            }).catch((error)=>{
                console.log(error);
                setEmailVerificationSent(false);
        });
    }else{
        console.log("You have not logged in yet!")
    }
}
```

Below is the code for allowing users to **sign up**:

```
export const firebaseAuthServiceSignUpWithEmailAndPassword= (username:string,email: string, password: string, callback: (isSuccess:boolean)=>void) =>{
    const auth = getAuth();
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in
            const user = userCredential.user;
            postAccount(username, email, password, user.uid);
            callback(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            const errorCode = error.code;
            const errorMessage = error.message;
            callback(false);
            // ..
        });
}
```

Below is the code for **signing in**:

```
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/start#sign_in_existing_users
export const firebaseAuthServiceSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email: string, password: string, callback: (isSuccess: boolean) => void) => {
    const auth = getAuth();
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            // Signed in
            const user = userCredential.user;
            console.log(user);
            console.log(user.emailVerified);
            callback(true);
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        callback(false);

    });
}
```

Below is the Firebase Console regarding email address verification and I set the link to be linked to a EmailVerifiedPage, which is the second the picture:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I don't at first glance see what's going wrong here. Signing out and in again should definitely give you a new ID token with the latest state from the server, so it seems like the user is not marked as verified on the server. Is that last screenshot the page that is rendered by Firebase Authentication when you click the link in the email? Or is it a page you made? If the latter, what is the link you get in the email, and what happens when you click on it?

Comment: The last page is not a page rendered by Firebase but one made by myself. The link that I get from the email redirects me to the to the last page as shown above. The url is the same.

Comment: It's unusual for the email sent from Firebase Authentication to contain a link to a page on your `localhost`, but if it does: your code in that page will need to call the Firebase API to verify the email address by calling `applyActionCode` passing the OOB code and email address as shown here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you've created a [custom email handler](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) page to handle the email verification. In that case your code in that page will need to call the Firebase API to verify the email address by calling `applyActionCode` passing the OOB code and email address as shown here: